# Finding mail queue using snmpwalk in php

Tags: php, snmp

I want to write a script in `PHP`, that is the same as `snmpwalk` command in `linux`. I want to find the queue mail using that. the inputs are host ip address and `mib` value.

The command in linux:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -cMTA@Rel@y 10.234.125.250   .1.3.6.1.4.1.9999.44.1
```

The result is:

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.9999.44.1.4.1.2.9.47.98.105.110.47.98.97.115.104.1 = STRING: "45"
```

I want the queue value as the result (that is 45 in the above example)

I read [snmprealwalk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmprealwalk.php) and [snmpget](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmpget.php) functions, but they didn't do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the SNMP walk implementation in PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
$a = snmpwalk("10.234.125.250", "MTA@Rel@y", ".1.3.6.1.4.1.9999.44.1"); 

foreach ($a as $val) {
    echo "$val\n";
}

?>
```